# Accessing Secure Websphere MQ from Java/JMS

Tags: java, security, jms, ibm-mq

I need some help with using JMS to write to Secure MQ.

Our middleware team has decided to start securing MQ objects and they have asked us to start using the secure MQ queues.

Most of our applications that write to MQ are Websphere applications although we do have some stand-alone clients as well.

Our websphere version is WAS 8.5 and MQ version is 7.5

What different types of options are available to access secure queues from java - as a producer and also as a consumer?

Is there any document / tutorial / code sample that will help with understanding how can I use Java / JMS to write to a secure queue?  What kind of information do I need to gather to do more research on this topic?

One of the comments they have made is - The preference is that the client id is configured by the websphere / MQ administrators and the developers should not know that.

Answer (score 0):

> Our middleware team has decided to start securing MQ objects and they
>   have asked us to start using the secure MQ queues.

There is no such thing as "secure MQ queues".  Did your company purchase IBM's WMQ AMS and you want to encrypt messages?

Or are you looking for how to configure your JMS application to use MQ SSL?

> One of the comments they have made is - The preference is that the
>   client id is configured by the websphere / MQ administrators and the
>   developers should not know that.

The deployment team should be responsible for setting the UserID and Password (and not the developers).

Comment: Yes, I think I am looking for example of configuring the JMS application to use MQ SSL.  I do not know other options, available to achieve this.  If there are any, please let me know, so I can research moreon it.

The IDs will be set by the deployment team - I think what they mean here is that the development team shouldn't know the Id / password or in other words, the id / password to access the Queue should not be put in the client code.

Could you give me an example of using MQ SSL with JMS?

Comment: Well, google should give you lots of hits and here is a list: http://www.capitalware.biz/library_wmq.html#MQSeriesSSLDoc